# Latex input file from git toplevel folder

Tags: git, latex

I am organizing some personal notes written in `LaTeX` in a `git` repository. The folder structure is:

```
> header
> topic A
>> subtopic A1
>> ...
> topic B
>> subtopic B1
>> ...
```

I want to collect all my macros in the `header` folder and reference them within the individual LaTeX docs via `\input`. How can I write the `\input` command without having to know which folder the file is in a-priori? (So that if I move a file I don't have to rewrite code)

It should be something like `\input{<git rev-parse --show-toplevel>/header/my_maros}`

However, there are two issues:

1. How to execute the `git` command from within LaTeX?
2. Does not work if `git` is not installed (i.e. if I want to share notes with someone else who does not have `git` installed)

Is there a pure `LaTeX` solution (ideally operating system independent)? Or is there a better solution altogether?

Comment: If you would add the top level folder to your texinputs variable, it would not matter where the files are. Something like `export TEXINPUTS=.:/path/to/the/toplevel/folder//:` (notice the `//` - this will make sure files in subfolders are found)

Comment: @samcarter thank you for your suggestion, but I am looking for a solution that works with zero extra setup if the whole folder was copy pasted to another system that had only LaTeX installed.